# How to Create a New Table With a Unique Index in an Active Record / Rails 4 Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I create a new table, through a rails migration, and add an unique index to it?

In the docs I found how to add a index to a table after it's been created, but how do you do both -- create the table, and add the unique index -- in the same migration file?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here's the full process:

Generate a migration ( `rails generate migration CreateFoos bar:string` or `rails g migration CreateFoos bar:string` )

Modify your migration to look something like this:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :bar, :null => false

      t.index :bar, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: rails g migration add_bar_to_foos bar:uniq   

(which you'll find in the answers below, too)

Comment: This no longer works in Rails 7 (and probably even older versions). The comment below is more relevant these days:

`t.string :name, index: { unique: true }`

Answer (score 66):

A more compact way:

```rb
class CreateFoobars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foobars do |t|
      t.string :name, index: {unique: true}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18):

After generating a migration `rails generate migration CreateBoards name:string description:string`

In the migration file, add index as shown below:

```
class CreateBoards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :boards do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.string :description

     t.timestamps
   end

   add_index :boards, :name, unique: true

 end
end
```

Comment: I usually use this method so the added index is easily spotted but the other answer is cooler in ruby style!  Cheers to both!

Answer (score 15):

You can create the table and index with the generator without changing the migration file

For a unique index

```
rails generate model CreateFoos bar:string:uniq
```

For a non-unique index

```
rails generate model CreateFoos bar:string:index
```

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5, you can provide index options along with column definition.

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.string :key, null: false, index: {unique: true}
  t.jsonb :value

  t.timestamps
end


Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
id         | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass)
key        | character varying           |           | not null |
value      | jsonb                       |           |          |
created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
updated_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
  "table_name_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  "index_table_name_on_key" UNIQUE, btree (key)
```