# Remove uniqueness of index that is named

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to remove the uniqueness off a postgresql column index in my rails 4.1 app.

The original migration included:

```
add_index :customer_action_plan_objectives, :customer_action_plan_id,:unique => true, :name => "plan_id"
```

I have tried

```
class ChangeIndexUniquenessCustomerActionPlanObjectives < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :customer_action_plan_objectives, :customer_action_plan_id
    add_index :customer_action_plan_objectives, :customer_action_plan_id, :name => "plan_id"
  end
end
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Index name 'index_customer_action_plan_objectives_on_customer_action_plan_id' on table 'customer_action_plan_objectives' does not exist
```

Is this an issue caused by ":name => "plan_id"" or something else? My current solution has been sourced form [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635825/how-to-create-a-new-table-with-a-unique-index-in-an-active-record-rails-4-migr).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 'remove_index' method is trying to derive the index name from the parameters you are passing. But the add_index above that is passing a 'name' parameter. 
Thought I haven't used this method, the documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_index shows that you can pass name into the remove_index.